# apex test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, api, failing-tests

Pretty straight forward question: is it possible to run tests without using the Developer Console? I've reached my 5,000 max API Calls and I don't want to wait till' tomorrow to be able to keep testing my classes.

The following error appears when I try to, for example, save a file through Eclipse:

[image]

Best regards.

Comment: Sorry, but how running tests and counting API Calls are connected? Is SFDC count every test run as API Call?

Comment: @Chiz From my own experience, simple things like, for example, using Eclipse to save a file, uses api calls. My major part come from running tests since I didn't have this problem up until now (when I started developing test classes).

Answer (score 3):

### Your question:

Is it possible to run tests without using the Developer Console?
Yes, it is.

1. You could use the metadata API (or any tool which use it Eclipse, Sublime, etc).
2. You could use the setup interface (Setup > Develop > Apex Classes) button:

[image]

3. You could use the developer console
4. Or you could build your own classes to run the test using `ApexTestQueueItem`

[here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_unit_tests_running.htm) the official doc of running tests

### Api calls

However, I think that all those options use api call (I'm not sure about UI button). So I don't think that can achieve this having consumed the api calls.

Comment: First option I've already tried, it gives me the Total Limit Exceeded error, not only with Run Tests but Saving a file aswell (this api calls being maxed out doesn't let me use Eclipse anymore). 
The second onde I can run it, but no % is shown anywhere. Am I looking at the wrong place?

Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: As far as I know the only "standard" place to see the % coverage is the developer console. Eclipse, Sublime, others need api calls.

Comment: @RuiRocha, can you open a class in your org and discover % there?

Comment: I would contact support and try to get them to increase the limit for you.  They generally only will do this temporarily, so you need to make your case to them.

Comment: @Chiz No, that's the problem, even if I do "Run All Tests" I wanted to do this at least for a single test class, since otherwise I don't know in which one is the coverage missing (I have like 10 test class to check atm). I can only do Develop > Apex Classes > Estimate your organization's code coverage

Comment: @sfdc_ninja Thanks for the idea but the problem is, even if they raise from 5,000 to 10,000, by tomorrow I will have the same problem again eventually since these ran out in a couple of hours...

Thanks everyone for the answers.